# GCP APIs requests without using them

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I have a look at one of my GCP projects under APIs & Services > Dashboard, I can see requests for "Cloud Pub/Sub API" although I do not use this API, all requests are errors, so 100% error rate.

I can see similar situations in other projects with other APIs, the above is only an example.

So far I have tried to find out more within: Logging > Logs Explorer, but it seems that APIs are not included in these logs. In addition I have tried to click on the API within APIs & Services > Dashboard and investigate the menu items "Overview", "Metrics", "Quotas" and "Credentials" but I could not find anything which would describe who/what uses this API.

Any ideas?

EDIT (12. Nov 2020):
I am using the following resources in this project:

- App Engine
- Compute Engine
- Cloud Storage
- BigQuery
- Cloud SQL

Comment: Can you describe the component that you use in your project?

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on there, best for you would be to open a ticket with support directly if you are eligible.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: I have listed up all the used resources.

Comment: Several services are able, by configuration to publish to PubSub. You can try to deactivate the PubSub API, then go to error reporting and to see if one of your services has errors. It's hard to say without knowing how did you configure your project components.